# Is there away to see the internal process of a software?

Tags: monitoring

I would like to be able to see/monitor how a software "works" once it's running. For example I would like to see what happens internally when you click on a button, or any other interaction within an app. I tried using Instruments (xcode), but Instruments only let me select an application that's already running. Which means I always miss the initial process of when the application starts running.

I am not looking for resource usage, just trying to understand how the internal files work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention what version of Mac OS X you're running, but if you're running a version between 10.4 and 10.9.x, then [fseventer](http://fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software%3Afseventer%3Astart) may be useful if you're trying to see what files and ports are accessed while you launch, use, or quit an application.

Comment: I think this is as good as it's going to get. Thank you for pointing out that software.

Comment: Also have a look at opensnoop.

Answer (score 0):

Open Activity Monitor
Select the process you want to monitor
Click the "Gear" icon and choose "Sample Process"

NB: I am not claiming this will be of any use to you. It is generally only helpful for tracking bugs for someone who has the source code.

Comment: I have used Activity Monitor, but I can't get the sample process until the software it's already running. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, of course not. How are you expecting to see what a program is doing while it is not doing anything?

Comment: I don't. But I do expect to see it as soon as it starts. The first process. With activity monitor I miss those first initial seconds.

Comment: Maybe if we knew why you were trying to do this or what you were trying to find out...

Comment: Just curious about how some processes work. The fseventer software that  @eyer pointed out works quite well. It gives you a visualization of all files that are being accessed in the computer at any given time. And you can also use some filters to help narrow down the paths you're watching.